# Foreach retun in shortcode

Tags: plugins, php

I have this function which lists the posts from other wordpress site using api.
But when i put [my-shortcode] i get blank result.
if i remove the shortcode function then i get the output but above the header. this means its working but when i try to put it in shortcode i get blank output.

```
function my_shortcode_function() {
    $feed = get_remote_api_data();
    $html = '';
foreach($feed as $post) {
   $title= $post->title->rendered;
    $image= $post->featured_media;
    $excerpt= $post->featured_media;
    $link = $post->link;

    $html = '<div class="featuredImage"><a href="'.$link.'"><img src="'.$image.'" /></a></div>'; //the image and the link
     $html .= '<div class="title"><h3><a href="'.$link.'">'.$title.'</a></div></h3>'; //the title and the link
     $html .= '<div class="excerpt">hello</div>'; //the excerpt

} //end foreach loop
  return $html; 
}
add_shortcode('my-shortcode','my_shortcode_function');
```

Comment: is there a reason you're using a global variable instead of creating `$feed` inside the shortcode function? This is probably because there is no `global $feed;` inside your shortcode function but a global variable should be unnecessary. Also your shortcode never checks if `$feed` is `false` and assumes it worked

Comment: ok i put the $feed inside the function & it works but only returns 1 post out of 5.  see the updated code

Comment: because on every loop you discard `$html` and reset it with an `=` instead of appending with `.=`. I don't think these are WordPress problems, these look like general programming/PHP mistakes